# StablexUI for Haxe NME not working

Tags: flashdevelop, haxe, nme

I am using this simple code snipet in nme to use the StablexUI for haxe but all I get is a blank white screen.

```
UIBuilders.init();

//Create our UI
Lib.current.addChild( UIBuilder.buildFn('ui.xml')() );
```

The ui.xml file contains the xml for the UI has found below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Root element of our UI -->
<HBox w="800" h="600" skin:Paint-border="8" skin:Paint-color="0x005d00" skin:Paint-        borderColor="0x003a00" skin:Paint-alpha="0.8" childPadding="50">

<Slider
    w  = "400"
    h  = "50"

    min   = "-100"
    max   = "100"
    value = "0"

    vertical = "false"

    skin:Paint-border="2"
    skin:Paint-color="0xFFFFFF"
    skin:Paint-corners="[20]"

    slider-w        = "50"
    slider-heightPt = "100"

    slider-skin:Gradient-colors = "[0xFF0000, 0x000000]"
    slider-skin:Gradient-corners="[20]"
/>

<Slider
    w="50"
    h="400"

    min   = "-100"
    max   = "100"
    value = "0"

    vertical = "true"

    skin:Paint-border="2"
    skin:Paint-color="0xFFFFFF"
    skin:Paint-corners="[20]"

    slider-widthPt  = "100"
    slider-h = "50"

    slider-skin:Gradient-colors = "[0xFF0000, 0x000000]"
    slider-skin:Gradient-corners="[20]"
/>
```

I am using the example from github repo

Answer (score 4):

I'm maintainer of StablexUI.
Can you provide your ui.xml and related files (e.g. defaults.xml, skins.)

Edit: It works for me on every platform. Did you try to build for different platforms? What about flash target? What are your haxe, hxcpp and nme/openfl versions?